# Using bool (return Type) to handle exceptions or pass exception to client?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging, try-catch

I am trying to find out the best way of handling exceptions, I have a number of layers to my application and started to use a return type of BOOL i.e. if it fails then return False and if it succeeds return True..

This works great in methods like SaveMyRecord(somerecord);  as i am passing in values and don't require anything returned so i can use the return type of bool to indicate if it succeeds or not.

But then it got me thinking that things like GetMyRecord() actually returns type of IQueryable  hence i can't use a bool to tell me if it failed or not.

The thing is i am handle alot of my errors where they happen with try and catch and hence don't want the client to receive an exception.

Maybe there is a better way, i then got thinking about using OUT parameters BUT this means i need to change the signature of all methods and add aditional params..

Maybe i should be passing the exception back to the CLIENT and handling it there?

Is there some standards or any docs to adivse best practices?

Comment: What are you using for server and client sides? Ex: WCF, ASMX, WinFoms, WebForms.

Comment: If you combine what @AlfredMeyers and @dove combined said, you'd have the answer I was planning on giving you.  Rather than adding what they said in one combined answer, I'd say read both of them.  Most importantly, though would be to read up.  +1 to each of them.

Comment: Are the services facing the internet? What are the security requirements? Are you concerned about exposing potentially unsafe information through exceptions?

Comment: @AlfredMyers - I am using a number of layers, 1 is behind a wcf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Bubble up** the exception to the CLIENT and handle it there.  Definitely pass it in full detail all the way up. Most best practices almost entirely agree on this, always finally handle on the perimeter, in this case the CLIENT, though in other cases that could be a web service.

**Only catch** if you want to **log** it, **add more info** to it or try and **recover** from a particular exception.  In each case you will will either throw a new exception with the original as the inner or simply 'throw' the original as is, and as pointed in comments don't 'throw ex'

This question is a **near duplicate** and you'd find lots of existing very well answered questions on SO.  I answered a [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448025/c-best-practice-error-handling-and-passing-error-messages/1448029#1448029) only yesterday

Comment: As far as catching only to log, this is OK as long as you also rethrow the exception after it has been logged. If you do that make sure to just use the `throw` statement instead of `throw ex` so you don't break the stack trace.

Comment: @Scott absolutely. also if you're adding more info then put original exception as an inner exception to the new one you create.  and if you can't recover after n times then throw as you say.  thinking you know all this ;) but thought it might help other readers

Comment: Agreed with Scott and from personal experience: if you try to build a more than moderately complex application where your error conditions are based on boolean return values you will very soon see spaghetti coding and realize how little you know about what went wrong when a false is returned from the depths of a subroutine written months ago. The basic problem is that return values have to be threaded up to code that can handle it via many layers whereas exceptions "bubble up" to where they can be handled by design.

Comment: THanks everyone for some great advice!! - I am going to apply it now!!.. Basically i am going ot use try - catch and Log and throw; to rethrow the same error so that it bubbles up to the client where i will handle it..

Answer (score 5):

You should start reading [Design Guidelines for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx)

Then, depending on your scenario, you should take other considerations into account such as Exception Shielding.

For instance: If you are using web services (ASMX or WCF) as a back-end, you may want to take a look at [Improving Web Services Security](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurityGuide) and read the parts concerning exception handling.

Answer (score 4):

If a method can't do it's job, it should throw an exception. Never return an exception as a result.

Answer (score 2):

The approach that is recommended and considered a best practice is to use exceptions. You can (and should) read the [Framework Design Guidelines (2nd Ed.)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613), which has guidelines for exceptions and the try-parse pattern.

There are a few problems with using return codes (either numeric or boolean), the two biggest being:

- Easily overlooked/ignored by programmers.
- Can't be used in all situations. What happens if your constructor fails? It's not possible for you to return a value explicitly from a constructor.

As for when to handle exceptions, you should only handle them when you can do something meaningful about the exception. The problem with always handling exceptions so the client never sees them is that you can end up handling an exception that you shouldn't have and cause more problems later (like actually loosing data).

Answer (score 1):

This a great question!

Don't code for exception. For the most part pretend they never happened. I worry about exception in two places: Displaying error feedback to the user and resource management (i.e. closing an open file when a exception is throw).

Answer (score 1):

One common pattern MS seems to like is to have a ComputeSomething() method which returns 'int', and a TryComputingSomething() method which accepts a reference to an integer and returns Boolean.  The latter, when successful, stores its computation in the passed-in variable and returns True; if it fails for an "expected" reason, it returns False.  Note that unexpected failures in either routine may throw exceptions.

In some cases, it may be helpful to use a different pattern, and have a routine accept a delegate to be invoked in case of trouble.  That delegate could either return an exception, or cause the underlying routine to return false, or possibly do other things.  Note that at the time the delegate runs, information will be available which would be destroyed before any exception could be caught.  For example, if a routine is supposed to read lines from a file and convert characters 20-37 into a Date, it may be helpful to log the entire input line if there's a parsing error.  Using a passed-in delegate, one could do that; without such a thing, it would be much harder.