# checking collection of functions if equals to false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a group of methods that bring back a  true / false deppending on the outcome.
I have a collection of 3 - 4 methods and if any of these return false then throw an error.

But to check these all I can think of is

```
if(!myfunction) OR (!myOtherFunction) OR (!myOtherOtherFunction) 
return error
```

basically stacking on check ontop of each other. 
Is there a way I can more egelgent way to do this?

Comment: do your functions share the same syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You methods should only return true or false if they are evaluating booleans.
If you want to actually trap for errors, trap for errors. See [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448452/using-bool-return-type-to-handle-exceptions-or-pass-exception-to-client) for more reasons.

Use Exception handling, and have your functions throw exceptions.
Then, your surrounding code traps for (specific) exceptions, and handles them appropriately.

```
try {
  myfunction();
  myOtherFunction();
  myOtherOtherFunction();
}
catch (MyCustomException ce) {
  // do something specific with a specific error
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  // do something with the exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Method1, Method2, Method3 (for example) all have the same signature (take same type parameter, return bool), you can:

```
bool Method1(YourParamType arg) { }
bool Method2(YourParamType arg) { }    
bool Method3(YourParamType arg) { }

...

List<Func<YourParamType, bool>> validators = new List<Func<YourParamType, bool>>
    {
        Method1,
        Method2,
        Method3
    }

...

if (!validators.All(m => m(arg)) return error;
```

If your methods take no paramers, can just change to `Func<bool>` instead:

```
bool Method1() { }    
bool Method2() { }
```

bool Method3() { }

...

```
List<Func<bool>> validators = new List<Func<bool>>
    {
        Method1,
        Method2,
        Method3
    }

...

if (!validators.All(m => m()) return error;
```

Similarly, you can use `Func<YourParamType1, YourParamType2, bool>` etc if the methods take more than one arg.

If they have different signatures, you could do it all inline, but it gets ugly:

```
if (!new Func<bool>[] { () => Method1(arg1), () => Method2(arg1, arg2), () => Method3() }.Any())
    return error;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to report detailed information where the error occured you can do :

```
  bool error = false;
    string messageError = "An erorr has occured with :";

    if (!oneMethod())
    {
        error = true;
        messageError += "\n an error occured has occured with method one";
    }

if (!twoMethod())
    {
        error = true;
        messageError += "\n an error occured has occured with method two";
    }

if (error)
 DisplayError(messageError);
```

otherwise you can just return at the first found error.
You can encapsulate all this in a validate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<bool> foo1 = ...
Func<bool> foo2 = ...
Func<bool> foo3 = ...
var foos = new List<Func<bool>> {foo1, foo2, foo3};
bool error = foos.Any(foo => !foo());
```

Comment: @JRoughan That would return success and not error as the OP requested