# Best way to Handle Exceptions in C# Catch Block

Tags: exception, try-catch

Best way to Handle Exceptions in C# Catch Block.I have no other choice but to Log the error to SQL DB in Catch block.Howver i am wondering what is the best way to catch exception if caught in Catch block itself?

Comment: try
{
throw;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//Log error to DB
Whats best can be done here if error happens while logging to DB
}

Comment: It depends. What do you *want* to happen if the logging throws an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separate class to handle error reporting, and expose a function to handle logging the error in the DB.
I found this guide useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Some code that I have used in the past looks like:

```
try{
    throw;
}
catch(Exception ex){
    LoggingClass.LogError(some paramaters,ex.tostring());
}
```

and then your logging class could look like

```
public static class LoggingClass {

    public static void LogError(some paramaters, ex.tostring()){

        //try to log to database


        //catch and report error in some other way
    }

}
```

I used this article as a reference in the past because I liked the idea of logging to a text file (in the event of a DB error) and then displaying a "nice" message to the user.

[C# best practice error handling and passing error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448025/c-sharp-best-practice-error-handling-and-passing-error-messages)

Comment: Thanks Will...for looking into it so essentially there is no end:) but we can make it like 99% fail-safe thanks for your suggestion.i really appreciate you taking out time and responding to it