# C# ERROR Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string principal, rate, years;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        principal = loantextBox4.Text;
        rate = ratetextBox5.Text;
        years = yearworktextBox2.Text;

        outputlabel5.Text = principal * ((rate * (1 + rate) ^ years) / ((rate + 1) ^ years) - 1))));
```

What needs to be fixed I keep getting an error saying operator "*" cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.

Comment: google does not work from your part of the world..? also look up what `casting` is as well as `Convert.ToInt32 or Decimal` Method does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot apply mathematical operations on a `string` variable and thus you need an `int` or `double` type. I have used `int`. Secondly When you try to get the TextBox data in the int variable it would not be possible because `TextBox.Text` would return a string. Now You can convert the `TextBox.Text` to a `int` using `Convert.ToInt32`. If you try to put the values of the `Textbox` to int variable without conversion, it will give you an error stating

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

and it would not even compile the program.

Whereas letz say if the user input in not a number and it we try to Convert it. For example the user input is "Mohit" and when it tries to convert the `Convert.ToInt32("Mohit");` it will throw an exception. stating

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

You can avoid getting exception or to handle the wrongly input from the user you can use [Try and Catch Block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394690/3796048)

Hope this code will give you the idea

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int principal, rate, years;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        principal = Convert.ToInt32(loantextBox4.Text);
        rate = Convert.ToInt32(ratetextBox5.Text);
        years = Convert.ToInt32(yearworktextBox2.Text);

        outputlabel5.Text = (principal * ((rate * (1 + rate) ^ years) / ((rate + 1) ^ years) - 1)).ToString();
```

Comment: This leaves out what happens if the text is not convertible to int.

Comment: `it would not even compile the program.`  The program would compile just fine.  If you have something that cannot be converted at runtime, Convert.ToInt32() throws a FormatException.

Comment: @EricJ.: I mean to say "Textbox to int variable without conversion". Updated as stated by you.

Comment: Why would you advise using a try/catch block instead of using `.TryParse()`?  Don't use exceptions for logic flow.  Invalid input is a reasonably expected condition which can be checked with a simple conditional.

Answer (score 2):

You can't multiply strings.  You *can*, however, multiply numbers.  Convert your numeric strings to numbers.  For example:

```
int years;
if (!int.TryParse(yearworktextBox2.Text, out years))
{
    // string value wasn't numeric, maybe show an error?
    // probably return from here as well, since the logic can't continue
}
// here the "years" value can be used for calculations
```

Remove the `string` variables you have, replace them with numeric values (`int`, `decimal`, `double`, etc. where appropriate) which are populated by parsing the input strings using `.TryParse()` (and handling errors accordingly), then you can use those values in your calculations.

Comment: You should probably show an *else* in the example code as processing will continue with a non-parsed *years* unless there is a return from the *if* block.

Comment: @EricJ.: Fair point.  There are a number of ways to arrange the logic, depending on what the OP is trying to accomplish overall.  Personally I'm a fan of checking for negative conditions and returning vs. putting primary business logic in `else` blocks.

Comment: Yep.  He seems to be a beginner, so it's probably best to be very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of your inputs are strings. You can't multiply a string.

What you need to do instead is change them to a number format. Probably just `int` should be fine.