# How to handle exceptions: "ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:"

Tags: c#, oop

I created a class dubPrime that takes an integer that must be a double digit. If it isn't a double digit the program is supposed to throw an exception. However my program crashes and outputs "[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION" whenever I try to create an object that is not a double digit.
*I used the factory design pattern so that the object wouldn't be created if it doesn't meet the standards.

Is there a way to circumvent this so that my program doesn't crash?

```
    private DubPrime(bool upArg, bool enabledArg, uint xArg){
        x = xArg;
        up = upArg;
        enabled = enabledArg;
    }

    public static DubPrime GetDubPrime(bool upArg = true, bool enabledArg = true, uint xArg = lowerLimit){
        //x must be double digit
        if(xArg<lowerLimit || xArg>upperLimit) 
            throw new ArgumentException("x should be a double digit");
        else{
            return new DubPrime(upArg, enabledArg, xArg);
        }
    
    }
```

Update: Whenever I try to add a try/catch block the compiler says "not all code paths return a value." Is it necessary to return something? Could I throw an exception and not have it return something?

```
   public static DubPrime GetDubPrime(bool upArg = true, bool enabledArg = true, uint xArg = lowerLimit){
        try{
            if(xArg<lowerLimit || xArg>upperLimit) 
                throw new ArgumentException("x should be a double digit");
            else{
                return new DubPrime(upArg, enabledArg, xArg);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the code that throws the exception, but where is the code that catches it?

Comment: Whenever I try to add a try/catch block it requires me to return something and won't compile. (Updated the question)

Comment: @KevinKhong Normally you would catch the exception in the function that calls `GetDubPrime`. Inside `GetDubPrime` itself, you can just handle the error case directly, with an `if/else` block for example. There is no need to throw an exception just to catch it a few lines later.

Comment: If you throw an exception and don't catch it, the program terminates. So, catch the exception. See duplicate. For your other problem **please search the site for the exact error message**. That particular error is already thoroughly covered here. If after researching the error you still can't figure it out, post a new question making clear what research you've done and what _specifically_ you can't figure out.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505471/how-often-should-i-use-try-and-catch-in-c. You can write a factory method that follows the `Try...()` pattern, i.e. returns a `bool` value, and stores a success result in an `out` parameter, rather than throwing an exception. Alternatively, if you insist on throwing an exception, the factory method isn't helpful; you might as well throw the exception from the constructor of the type, because that will work just as well to prevent an invalid object from being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to outside of `GetDubPrime` catch the `ArgumentException` that you throw inside it. If nothing catches the exception the program exits.

Something like:

```
(...)
try 
{
   x = GetDubPrime(...);
} 
catch(ArgumentException ex) 
{
  // bad data, do something
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  x = 0; // or whatever is necessary
}
(...)
```